# how to send csv file to other server using wp_remote_post?

Tags: plugin-development, api, wp-remote-post

I am facing issue while sending csv file to api.
when i use simple php curl request it works fine for me and it sends the file to server.
here is my php code

```php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $curlurl,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'csv_file' => new CURLFILE($csv_file_path), 
        'filename' => $file_name, 
        'website' => $site_url
    ),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $doobert_api_token_value . ''
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

but when i try to send same file using wp_remote_post it calls api but i does not send file to request.
here is my wordpress code

```php
$request_body = array(
    'body' => array(
        'csv_file' => new \CURLFile($csv_file_path, 'text/csv', $file_name.'.csv'),
        'filename' => $file_name,
        'website' => $site_url,
    ),
);
                
print_r($request_body);
    
$request_args = array(
    'headers' => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $doobert_api_token_value,
        'Content-Disposition' => 'form-data; name="file"; filename="' . $file_name . '"',
    ),
    'body' => $request_body['body'],
);
    
$response = wp_remote_post($curlurl, $request_args);
         
$response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
```

anyone can solve this issue?

Comment: If the first code is working - what is the desire to change it to the second snippet?

Answer (score 0):

mirror issue in request body and headers ou can adjust your code to properly send the CSV file using `wp_remote_post()`

The `csv_file` parameter is set to a `CURLFile` object, which represents the file to be uploaded. This should correctly include the CSV file in the request body.

```
// Set up the request body
$request_body = array(
    'csv_file' => new CURLFile($csv_file_path, 'text/csv', $file_name.'.csv'),
    'filename' => $file_name,
    'website' => $site_url,
);

// Set up the request headers
$request_headers = array(
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $doobert_api_token_value,
);

// Set up the request args
$request_args = array(
    'headers' => $request_headers,
    'body' => $request_body,
);

// Send the request
$response = wp_remote_post($curlurl, $request_args);

// Check for errors
if (is_wp_error($response)) {
    $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
    echo "Error: $error_message";
} else {
    // Handle response
    $response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);
    $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    echo "Response Code: $response_code\n";
    echo "Response Body: $response_body\n";
}
```